# Undevelopable land European Union

Tags: qgis, elevation

I would like to calculate how much of the land in the European Union exhibits slopes above a certain threshold (let's say 15%) in order to have a precise measure for undevelopable land. I'm working with NUTS-3 level data and would need to match it with some kind of elevation data. I found a few possible data sources for this:

- https://global.jaxa.jp/press/2015/05/20150518_daichi.html
- http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/srtmdata/

Has anyone worked with this kind of data?

I'm a bit lost on how to proceed.

Comment: https://www.geodose.com/2018/02/how-to-download-srtm-elevation-data-qgis.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following link summarizes an approach that works here:

[How to calculate the relative share of an area of a circle that has a slope >15% in Germany](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190714/how-to-calculate-the-relative-share-of-an-area-of-a-circle-that-has-a-slope-15)